# not able to find the variables sqlite for django project

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am creating demo django project in PyCharm. So I keep closing and re-opening the PyCharm. But I have noticed that once I reopen my django project in PyCharm, and go to sqlite command prompt through `python manage.py shell`, and look for the previously created models, I get below error

```
>>> b.id
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

but when I execute the command

```
 Album.objects.all()
```

I do get the details of previously created models

```
>>> Album.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Album: yaad: Sonu Nigam>, <Album: : >, <Album: : Back Street Boys>, <Album: InComplete: Back Street Boys>, <Album: In The End: Linkin Park>]>
```

Is this a kind of any defect, or it's just me who get to see such situation, or am I missing something?

Python 3.6
django 1.11
pycharm 2017.2.3

Comment: What's confusing about the error message? You can't use something in the console before defining it.

Comment: I have already defined it, that is why I am asking this question, I have created "b = Album()" , that is why I can see the output through "Album.objects.all()"

Comment: *Where* did you define it? The console says you didn't.

Comment: `b = Album.objects.all()[0]` then print `b.id`.

Comment: @MD. Khairul Basar, your suggestion works. Thank you. But why this happens? When I create the models and reopen my pycharm, and sqlite shell, why it says "NameError"?

Comment: Because, you didn't define `b`.

Comment: @Daniel, may be you didn't understand my question. When I create the models in sqlite shell, and the console session is not closed, then I do not see the error. It's happening when I close all my application, and reopen them to continue my work

Comment: Yes. Why would you think the console would know about something you wrote in a previous session?

Comment: Because, when you store any data in the database, its there forever, unless it is deleted by any means.

Comment: The variables are not data that's stored in the database.

Comment: So, just to summarize my understanding, even though the models are there, but we need to tag those data to some varilable in sqlite before we start working on it, please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: *This has nothing to do with sqlite*. This is just Python. In Python you need to define variables before using them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of this problem is that you do not understand what the shell is.

Basically, the django shell gives you access to your models, but is other than that a normal python shell. You can not create model instances by doing something like:

```
b = Album.objects.all()[0]
```

What you did there is to save the first instance of your model in a python variable.

If you DO want to create a new model instance, you can use the create method of your model.`Album.objects.create()` (probably with some arguments).

I recommend you go back to the Django docs and follow the [Django Docs tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/)